# Beamerposter and \setmainfont incompatibility

Tags: typography, beamerposter

I made a *presentation* using beamer. In it I can change the font. I used:

```
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
```

And then I can freely alternate fonts in any place with, for example

```
\setmainfont{Frutiger Next Pro}
Some text in Frutiger
\setmainfont{Avenir Next Rounded Pro}
Some text in Avenir
```

I am trying to make a poster retaining the style, so I add:

```
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.6]{beamerposter}
```

After that, only works the `\setmainfont{Some Typography}` setted in the preamble. If I delete that line the fonts works fine (but of course I does not solve the problem because of the sizes and scales).

How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the problem?